# PHP/MySQL - Combining two tables in an array

Tags: php, mysql

SQL Noob here. My table is like this:

Main table

```
+-----------+-------------+
| talent_id | talent_name |
+-----------+-------------+
|         1 | Talent1     |
|         2 | Talent2     |
|         3 | Talent3     |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Education Table

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------+
| talent_id |   level   |           course            |
+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------+
|         1 | Post-Grad | Master in Something         |
|         1 | Post-Grad | Doctor in Something         |
|         1 | College   | BS Something Engineering    |
|         2 | College   | BS Something Science        |
|         2 | Post-Grad | Master in Something Science |
|         3 | College   | BS Computer Something       |
+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------+
```

Is it possible to combine the columns from the two tables in one query? I tried having separate queries (which worked, by the way) but I am having a hard time combining those two in an array. And if just in case that having separate queries is the better solution, Can you guys give me an idea how to iterate through the two array results and combine it into something like this:

```
Array( [0] => Array(
             'talent_id' => '1', 
             'talent_name' => 'Talent1', 
             'course' => Array('Master in something', 'Doctor in something', 'BS Something')),
       [1] => Array('talent_id' => '2', ...) )
```

Stack Overflow has been a great help for me since the start of my internship. And I want to thank all of you for that.

Comment: Try doing an LEFT JOIN: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you select your talents (indexed by their id) and your education. Here, I'll consider you just did 2 queries.
Then

```
foreach ($educations as $education) {
  $talents[$talent_id]['course'][] = $education;
}
```

You can also do it from a `LEFT JOIN`, but this kind of hydratation gets messy really quickly when you have multiple levels, and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem! I also tested the join statements suggested by the other answers here. The `FULL OUTER JOIN` works but the columns on the main table repeats depending on how many entries in education the talent has. I chose this because this is the easiest approach to the problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You should use a left join in your query :

```
SELECT m.talent_id,m.talent_name,e.level,e.course
FROM main AS m 
LEFT JOIN education AS e ON m.talent_id =  e.talent_id
```

Comment: Actually I am torn between this and the `foreach` solution since both produces the same result.

Comment: Well, it would actually depend on your preference and the needs. I personally prefer to do the joins in the database cause I find it much cleaner, and it uses less resources. Now depending on the rest of the code, it may not be the best. If you need to re-use your individual arrays later in the code, it may be good to use the foreach. If you only need that joined table, I would objectively say I think my answer is better...

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options

I often use:

```
SELECT talent.talent_id, talent.talent_name, education.course FROM talent, education WHERE education.talent_id = education.course
```

Downfall if the education is empty for a talent the talent doesn't shops up. Then you need to use a [join](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqljoin.php)

Answer (score 0):

You would typically use a join,

```
select * from main left join education using (talentid)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FULL OUTER JOIN to achieve that.
 A FULL OUTER JOIN combines the results of both left and right outer joins and returns all (matched or unmatched) rows from the tables on both sides of the table.

```
SELECT [COL-1], [COL-2] [, ... COL-N]
FROM [TABLE-1]
FULL OUTER JOIN [TABLE-2] ON [TABLE-1].[COLUMN NAME 1] = [TABLE 2].[COLUMN NAME 2]
```