# add column values from a selected range in code igniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

time-recods table i have

```
date
time in 
time out 
break in
break out
total_time
```

fields in my table. i have this sql query

```
public function showattendance(){

    $start      = $this->input->post('DATE_FROM');
    $end        = $this->input->post('DATE_TO');
    $employee   = $this->input->post('ID_NUM');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `attendance` WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '".$start."' AND '".$end."') AND (ID_NUM = '".$employee."')";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->result();
}
```

now all i want to do is when i already selected the rows between the dates i chose, i wanted to add the selected data from `total_time` column.

for example i got an array of

```
array = (
ID[0] => '1' , TOTAL_TIME[0]=>'09:30'
ID[1] => '2' , TOTAL_TIME[1]=>'07:30'
ID[2] => '3' , TOTAL_TIME[2]=>'08:30'
ID[3] => '4' , TOTAL_TIME[3]=>'09:00'
ID[4] => '5' , TOTAL_TIME[4]=>'05:45'

);
```

all i want to do is to add

```
TOTAL_TIME[0]+TOTAL_TIME[1]+TOTAL_TIME[2]+TOTAL_TIME[3]+TOTAL_TIME[4] = $value
```

Comment: you should mark some answer as correct @kev_m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets pretty simple to do so when you convert your result into array.. This might help you out from your problem.

[Here one column is later updated with new values in php. This may be helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731943/php-mysql-combining-two-tables-in-an-array)

-------------- Updated Answer ------------

Then your array should be like

```
<?php
$x =  array(
    array( ID => '1' , TOTAL_TIME =>'09:30'),
    array( ID => '2' , TOTAL_TIME =>'07:30'),
    array( ID => '3' , TOTAL_TIME =>'08:30'),
    array( ID => '4' , TOTAL_TIME =>'09:00'),
    array( ID => '5' , TOTAL_TIME =>'05:45'));

$total;
foreach($x as $y){
    $total+=$y["TOTAL_TIME"];
}
echo "Total Time = ".$total;

?>
```

Thus you can get your total time.

Comment: i already updated the question so it will be more understandable. thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understand from your question, you need to add the period from the start_date to end_date to do that run this code:

```
$res = $this->showattendance();// this is from your code
$this->db->update("time-recods");
$this->db->set("total_time",date_diff($res->time_in,$res->time_out));
$this->db->where('ID_NUM',$employee);
```

i wish it will help you :)

Comment: i already updated the question so it will be more understandable. thanks. :)